# Is there a list of everything that can be done with React ref's?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

So I find React useRef ref's extremely helpful. I use them a lot to control style, get clientWidth and much more but I know that I'm just barely scraping the tip of ref's functionality.

Can anyone provide a list of all of the different keys and objects that can be accessed with useRef? (And a brief description of what it sets or returns)

I.E.

```
ref.current.style - changes css style for the element
ref.current.clientWidth - returns the elements width
```

I have searched Google and ReactJS.org and I have been unable to find such a list.

Comment: It is effectively a reference to the DOM element (*if you use it like that*), so https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: I feel like it should be better labeled to specify that it was for useRef() but in hindsight calling it element should have been enough of a hint. If you can answer the question instead of commenting, I can mark your answer as correct and close this question.

Comment: `useRef` can be used for Elements, Components, and other things (values, such as an object, array, number, boolean, string...) too. It shouldn't be named as "element"

Comment: @Displayname it can be used with different ways. The important thing is what value you pass to it, that gets stored in the `current` property. If you use it on an element with `ref={theRefVariable}` then it gets the element as i mentioned. But you can manually set its value and use it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Everything about refs are given in the React documentation itself:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html.

Please note the subheading:

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

So if you are using refs to manipulate HTML Elements in your render, then you will be getting DOM nodes available in your browser. In simple terms, you get the same type of object when you access something like `window.document`, you get access to the properties and methods available on the traditional DOM node APIs for that particular element.

It's also possible to get refs to React Class Components, in that case, you get to access whatever properties and methods you get to access inside the component instance.

Please check the documentation to know more.

Comment: refs-and-the-dom is far from "Everything" in fact, this is exactly what I wasn't looking for. What I was asking for was a list of the objects that can be called from a ref like what Gabriele Petrioli linked to in his first comment. The issue that I had was that Reactjs.org did not create a separate page for react elements and react ref's since they have the same functions. This made it much more challenging to get results from an internet search.